# Access requested URL in webViewDidFinishLoad?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm very new to iOS development so please be gentle.

I understand that `webViewDidFinishLoad` will fire for each `<iframe>` plus the original html page.

I'm trying to find the URL of the request that resulted in that `webViewDidFinishLoad`. As far as I can tell, I can only access webView.request.mainDocumentURL.

I find this perplexing. Inside the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method, which fires also for each `<iframe>` and the original html request, you can access the URL in question, be it the iframe or the parent page.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"Parent page request: %@", request.mainDocumentURL);
    NSLog(@"Actual URL request: %@", [request URL]); // This returns what I want.
    return YES;
}
```

That first log statement will output the  url.

However, inside `webViewDidFinishLoad`

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSURLRequest* request = [webView request];
    NSLog(@"Parent page request: %@", request.mainDocumentURL);
    NSLog(@"Request outputs the parent, not the iframe: %@", [request URL]);
    // how do I access the <iframe> url?
}
```

Help me StackOverflow. My google-fu is weak and your wisdom is strong.

**EDIT:** I should be clear on the goal of this. I want to Do Stuff™ when the load event of the parent page fires, not for iframes. I want this to happen as soon as possible, so I don't want to wait until everything finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the UIWebView as your browser.  The scope of the object you are interrogating is at the browser level, the iFrames are more granular than that.  The URL that populates the iFrame is used to stream content for that section of the page, but for the purposes of the UIWebView, you only need to remember the main URL so the page can be managed (reloaded, etc...) as that URL clearly brings with it instructions as to how to manage the iFrame's content.

If you really need to those iFrame source URLS, simply extendeding UIWebView to hold an array of links (populate the array inside "`shouldStartLoadWithRequest`").  You can then do whatever you want with that list of links.

Good Luck.

Comment: My purpose is to do stuff inside `webViewDidFinishLoad` only when the original URL loads, I want to ignore the others. How can I figure out when that original (parent) request loads?

Comment: Your question seems to indicate you can ONLY access the parent (main) URL and you want to also see the source URLs for the page's iFrame components.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Each time `webViewDidFinishLoad` fires it shows the parent URL. I want to the execute some code only when the parent page finishes, not when an iframe finishes loading.

Comment: Why not execute your control logic in the larger "viewDidLoad" call on the overall UIView object?  Then you can be assured your active content has loaded before you proceed.